# Angular2+ changing email input value on input isnt working

Tags: angular, email, events, input

I am removing emojis from HTML inputs in material form fields on input event using a directive, that works alright. It does not work on my email form field, the event handler is firing, but the value does not change to what I expect

Here is my directive (Updated With  Mike S's suggestion)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[icNoEmojis]'
})
export class NoEmojisDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  private _removeEmojis(string: string): string {

    const regex: RegExp = /(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g;

    return string.replace(regex, '');

  }

  @HostListener("input", ["$event"])
  public onInput(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this._removeEmojis(this.elementRef.nativeElement.value)
  }
}
```

Here is my Input HTML

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input
      icNoEmojis
      matInput
      type="email"
      formControlName="email"/>

    <mat-error *ngIf="profileDetailsFormGroup.controls['email']?.hasError('email')">
      Email is not valid
    </mat-error>

    <mat-error *ngIf="profileDetailsFormGroup.controls['email']?.hasError('required')">
      Email is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Assuming this is on an `<input/>`, you dont need to use `event.target` since that is just the `elementRef` you inject in the constructor.

Comment: @MikeS. Thanks, that makes sense, i will be using that, although it does not solve my problem. It has something to do with the input being of type email

Comment: It works [fine for me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-no-emojis?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I see so, even after I make it a form group. The issue must be elsewhere. Thank you, really appreciate your effort

Comment: Check, adding an @ in the email allows emojis through and notice the console when that happens